# How to create recovery CD for Mac Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, backup, osx-mountain-lion

I'm working on a brand new Mac Mini with Mac os X 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion) and it didn't come with any recovery disks. How can I make recovery disks for free (i.e. not buying a license for Acronis or Symantec)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't probably even need any recovery disk. New Macs have a [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718) which allows you to download and reinstall OS X or for example erase a drive in Disk Utility.

If the Mac can't start up from the recovery partition, something like the contents of the recovery partition are downloaded from Apple's servers.

Comment: The Mac does have this but isn't this not safe because if the hard drive fails you're hooped? Isn't it like having the backup in the same place as the primary?

Comment: If the startup drive fails (or if you replace it with an empty drive), the contents of the recovery partition are downloaded from the internet. You don't really need to use recovery disk assistant unless that doesn't work or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apple's [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to clone the recovery partition from your computer's internal disk to something like a keychain drive (must be at least 1GB).